# Is 22,000,000 files and folders too many?

Tags: testdisk

Long story short: I should have had a backup.

Now I found myself using TestDisk to restore my entire operating system. However, it's taking a very long time to move along - at about 22 million files, I'm wondering at this point whether it's just taking a while to recover all of those darn temp files, or if it is hanging up. It still has not moved on past `/var/lib`.

The main errors in `testdisk.log` look like these:

```
Can't create file /media/ubuntu/Recovery/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtasn1-3:i386.shlibs/urandom/X11/pt/man5/netcat.1.gz/ncurses-bin/.Greek-TerminusBold20x10.psf.gz.Ct4hLl/Greek-Terminus22x11.psf.gz/PT154.so/lib/Blk/Suppleme.pl.dpkg-new/mmu.h.dpkg-new: Not a directory
Can't create file /media/ubuntu/Recovery/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtasn1-3:i386.shlibs/urandom/X11/pt/man5/netcat.1.gz/ncurses-bin/.Greek-TerminusBold20x10.psf.gz.Ct4hLl/Greek-Terminus22x11.psf.gz/PT154.so/lib/Blk/Suppleme.pl.dpkg-new/dma-mapping.h.dpkg-new: Not a directory
```

...

```
Can't create file /media/ubuntu/Recovery/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtasn1-3:i386.shlibs/urandom/X11/ja/tzdata.postrm/powerpc/include/asm.dpkg-new/scatterlist.h.dpkg-new/home/richie/.icedtea/cache/2/http/arcanists14.jagex.com/74/Microsoft.NET/50/partial-i386/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/America/Tortola: Is a directory
```

Or these:

```
ext2fs_read_inode(ino=825254982) failed with error 2133571369.
ext2fs_read_inode(ino=825254969) failed with error 2133571369.
ext2fs_read_inode(ino=825254982) failed with error 2133571369.
ext2fs_read_inode(ino=825254982) failed with error 2133571369.
ext2fs_read_inode(ino=825254982) failed with error 2133571369.
ext2fs_read_inode(ino=825254969) failed with error 2133571369.
```

My question, though, boils down to this: Is it normal to be seeing as many as 22 million files in the filesystem as a normal Linux user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not; my current system has under half a million.  I'd say testdisk is wasting your time.

Comment: Good to know an approximate file count for a system. As it turns out, you were correct, TestDisk turned 40 gigabytes into 500.